# How to decode whole number in .txt file into ascii using Python?

Tags: python, file-io, ascii, decode, data-conversion

I'm still a beginner in studying Python 3.
I try to read a "New_Memtrace.txt" file which is contains a line of numbers like this :
0000000000000000FFDF102F0000000000000000FFFFFFFF0000000000000000137F05000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012CCF3F00000000000000004000014000000000000000001F0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Note that there is not any space or newline inside that file (pure a line of number).
I want to decode the data into ASCII character for every 2 digits of the number as the Hexa (for example: 00 as NUL,1F as US on ascii table)

Then, I try to write this code , but there are some error while running.

```
in_file = open ("New_Memtrace.txt",'r')
in_byte_string = in_file.read()
bytes_object = bytes.fromhex(in_byte_string) #converts to bytes object
print(bytes_object)
ascii_string = bytes_object.decode("ASCII")  #convert to ASCII representation
print(ascii_string)
```

Convert to byte object successfully done, with output:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xdf\x10/\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x7f\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01,\xcf?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x01@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

But, an error occurred below the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ascii_string = bytes_object.decode("ASCII")         #convert to ASCII representation
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 8: ordinal not in
range(128)
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Your problem is `FF`. You can't decode that as ascii because it *isn't* ascii. Ascii goes up to `7F`.

Comment: Then, FF is on the Latin-1 group right? How can I decode all of the string both in ascii (00 until 7F) and Latin-1 (80 until FF)?